# appended images only show as strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append several images inside a div. My approach is as follows

```
var mylegends = document.getElementById('mylegends');
    for(let i=0; i<=images.length; i++){
        let img = images[i].currentSrc;
        mylegends.append(`<img src=${img}></img>`)
}
```

But instead of the images it shows the strings of the image elements. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Wrong commands and syntax. You don't need jQuery for this.

```
var mylegends = document.getElementById('mylegends');
for(let i=0; i<=images.length; i++){
  
  /* bad idea to use this method */
  // let img = images[i].currentSrc;
  // mylegends.innerHTML += (`<img src="${img}"/>`)

  /* preferable method */
  let image = document.createElement("img");
  image.src = images[i].currentSrc
  mylegends.appendChild(image);
}
```

If you want to use jQuery, the below should work

```
for(let i=0; i<=images.length; i++){
  let img = images[i].currentSrc;
  $('#mylegends').append(`<img src="${img}"/>`)
}
```

Comment: `...innerHTML +=` is generally not a good idea. It's quite an expensive operation as it has to serialise the entire contents of the element to HTML and then convert the string back to a different set of elements … and a side effect of that is to do things like destroy event handlers and reset the values of form controls.

Comment: Oh. I wasn't aware of this. Thank you. Editing my answer to use `.appendChild` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`mylegends` is a DOM Element, not a jQuery object.

Both have methods called `append()` but they work differently.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) for how append works on a DOM element.

> The ParentNode.append() method inserts a set of Node objects or DOMString objects after the last child of the ParentNode. DOMString objects are inserted as equivalent Text nodes.

If you want to insert a string of HTML to a DOM element then you want [the `insertAdjacentHTML` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```
mylegends.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<img src="${img}">`)
```

Aside: The end tag for `<img>` elements is forbidden, so don't include that.

Answer (score 0):

When a JavaScript method, or function, doesn't work as expected the easiest way to understand why is basically looking at the MDN documentation, which here says:

> The `ParentNode.append()` method inserts a set of Node objects or `DOMString` objects after the last child of the `ParentNode`. `DOMString` objects are inserted as equivalent Text nodes.

Therefore it's easy to see *why* you're getting HTML strings, rather than DOM nodes, appended to your content.

For example:

```js
let images = [{
    currentSrc: "https://via.placeholder.com/150/f90/fff"
  }],
  mylegends = document.getElementById('mylegends');

for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  let img = images[i].currentSrc;
  mylegends.append(`<img src=${img}>`);
}
```

```html
<div id="mylegends"></div>
```

Note that there were a couple of simple errors in your code:

1. `for(let i = 0; i <= images.length; i++)` means that your `for` loop will execute one more time than necessary (so there'll be an error about `images[i]` being undefined); I've changed that – above – to `for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++)`, and
2. an `<img>` element is a void element, therefore it has no closing tag

So, because DOMStrings are inserted as text nodes, we obviously need to create an `<img>` node to use with the `append()` method:

```js
let images = [{
    currentSrc: "https://via.placeholder.com/150/f90/fff"
  }],
  mylegends = document.getElementById('mylegends');

for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  let img = new Image();
  img.src = images[i].currentSrc;

  mylegends.append(img);
}
```

```html
<div id="mylegends"></div>
```

It's also worth noting that you could adjust the code to use `Array.prototype.forEach()`, which would have avoided the earlier problem of using an incorrect check in the `for` loop:

```js
let images = [{
    currentSrc: "https://via.placeholder.com/150/f90/fff"
  }],
  mylegends = document.getElementById('mylegends');

images.forEach(
  (obj) => {
    // here I use document.createElement('img') instead of
    // new Image(); there's little difference and it's merely
    // a personal preference:
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = obj.currentSrc;
    mylegends.append(img);
  });
```

```html
<div id="mylegends"></div>
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
- [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).
- [`Image()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image).
- [`ParentNode.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append).